# data repeater not showing image

Tags: c#, winforms

I need some help please. I have used a data repeater to display 
values from the database, all columns display values in the text boxes on the repeater except for the image. Am failing to convert byte back to image
here's my code for save to database

```
private void btnSave_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    byte[] imageBt = null;
    FileStream fstream = new FileStream(this.txtImgPath.Text,FileMode.Open,FileAccess.Read);
    BinaryReader Br = new BinaryReader(fstream);
    imageBt = Br.ReadBytes((int)fstream.Length);
    // byte[] pic = stream.ToArray();
    try
    {
        conDB.Open();
        OleDbCommand command = new OleDbCommand();
        command.Connection = conDB;
        command.CommandText = "insert into abaanaCC (CCSpn_CODE,CCFname,CCLname,CCMname,CCDOB,CCgender,CCSchool,CaClass,CCVillage,CCSiblings,CCGuardian,CCContact,CCImage)" +
                " values ('" + spn_codetxt.Text + "','" + txtfname.Text + "','" + lnametxt.Text + "','" + mnametxt.Text + "','" + DOBDTPicker1.Text + "','" + gendercomboBox.Text + "','" + schtxt.Text + "','" + classcomboBox.Text + "','" + villatxt.Text + "','" + siblingscombobx.Text + "','" + guardiantxt.Text + "','" + contacttxt.Text + "',@IMG) ";
        command.Parameters.Add(new OleDbParameter("@IMG",imageBt));
        //command.Parameters.AddWithValue("@IMG",pic);
        command.ExecuteNonQuery();
        MessageBox.Show("Record Saved");
    }
    catch (Exception ex)
    {
        MessageBox.Show("Unable to save" + ex);
    }
    conDB.Close();
}
```

then for the data repeater

```
private void Update_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        // TODO: This line of code loads data into the 'abaanaDataSet.abaanaCC' table. You can move, or remove it, as needed.
        this.abaanaCCTableAdapter.Fill(this.abaanaDataSet.abaanaCC);
        int c = this.abaanaDataSet.abaanaCC.Rows.Count;
        if (c > 0) ;
        {
            byte[] mydata = new byte[0];
            mydata = (byte[])(this.abaanaDataSet.abaanaCC.Rows[c-1]["CCImage"]);
            MemoryStream stream = new MemoryStream(mydata);
            cCImagePictureBox.Image = Image.FromStream(stream);

        }
```

}

Comment: Please add error messages or logs so It will be easier to help you. Thanks!

Comment: Apparently when i debug i get no error messages, everything works just fine except image doesn't appear in picture box on the data repeater

Comment: i am now getting the error: there is no row at position 14

Comment: Why are you doing `[c - 14]`?

Comment: i have changed it to the actual row but still no image

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Make sure you're actually getting valid image data from your dataset. This should work:

```
private void Form3_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    this.productPhotoTableAdapter.Fill(this.adventureWorks2014DataSet.ProductPhoto);

    byte[] mydata = (byte[])this.adventureWorks2014DataSet.ProductPhoto[100]["LargePhoto"];
    MemoryStream stream = new MemoryStream(mydata);
    pictureBox1.Image = Image.FromStream(stream);
}
```

[image]

Comment: yes i am getting valid images in the dataset but they are not appearing in the picture box in the data repeater control

Comment: how do you know it is valid image?

Comment: can you display an image in a picture box outside a data repeater?

Comment: it's appearing in the datagrid view on the same form, but inside the data repeater, the image does not appear, yet other fields appear just fine

Comment: Does you `cCImagePictureBox` display an image? Is that inside or outside a data repeater?

Comment: i don't see any reference to the data repeater... what is it called?

Comment: Shouldn't you be doing something like `dataRepeater1.ItemTemplate.Controls["cCImagePictureBox"].Image = ...`

Comment: it has still failed after referencing

Comment: `abaanaCCDataRepeater.ItemTemplate.Controls["cCImagePictureBox1"].BackgroundImage = Image.FromStream(stream);` also used `this.abaanaCCDataRepeater.ItemTemplate.Controls[this.cCImagePictureBox1.Image] = Image.FromStream(stream);` still not showing up

Comment: Try using `Image` property instead of `BackgroundImage`.

Comment: Do this: `abaanaCCDataRepeater.ItemTemplate.Controls["cCImagePictureBox1"].Imag‌​e = Image.FromStream(stream);`

Comment: that brings this error: `System.Window.Forms.Control` does not contain a definition for `Image` and no extension method `Image` accepting a first argument of type `System.Window.Forms.Control` could be found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?)

Comment: `PictureBox` definitely has an `Image` property. You can chech that on MSDN documentation. If `Controls["cCImagePictureBox1"]` is really a `PictureBox` then it should work. Perhaps you'll need to cast it.

Comment: I mean, you certainly need to cast it from `Control` to `PictureBox`.

Comment: the property that is there is `BackgroundImage`

Comment: Yes, but there's also an `Image` property, please try that one.

Comment: As per MSDN: _Image = Gets or sets the image that is displayed by PictureBox._

Comment: `Image` is specific to a `PictureBox`. `BackgroundImage` any `Control` has it.

Comment: even after casting, image has failed to appear in `datarepeater` though outside `datarepeater` image does appear `((PictureBox)this.abaanaCCDataRepeater.ItemTemplate.Controls["cCImagePictureBox1"]).Image = Image.FromStream(stream)`

Comment: haha okay but thanks a lot....let me keep trying harder, however am thinking of alternatives

Comment: i would use `DataGridView` instead, you just need to call `adapter.fill(table)`, and that's it....

Comment: how do you design a master detail from `DataGridView`

Comment: There's lots of tutorials on that. Here's one from [MSDN](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/vstudio/y8c0cxey%28v=vs.100%29.aspx)

Comment: finding a problem selecting image from other rows, by default it's selecting from the first row `byte[] mydata = (byte[])this.abaanaDataSet.abaanaCC.Rows[0]["CCImage"];
          MemoryStream stream = new MemoryStream(mydata);           
         this.PpicBox.Image =Image.FromStream(stream);`  how do i tweak this to select other rows under the cell click event

Comment: @ElijahAyeeta, please post it as a brand new question with more details about the code you have and send me the link to your question. This way, if I cannot solve it, someone else can. Thank you.

Comment: here's the link [http://stackoverflow.com/questions/32853725/how-to-create-master-detail-from-datagridview/32854111#32854111]

Comment: Thank you, i'll look into it as soon as I get a chance.

Comment: Hey, I'm glad for you, congrats!

Comment: please help me [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/37520758/how-to-add-the-value-of-a-column-in-database)