# How to create Master Detail from datagridview

Tags: c#, winforms, datagridview, master-detail

this code inserts in the database

```
 private void btnSave_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        byte[] imageBt = null;
        FileStream fstream = new FileStream(this.txtImgPath.Text,FileMode.Open,FileAccess.Read);
        BinaryReader Br = new BinaryReader(fstream);
        imageBt = Br.ReadBytes((int)fstream.Length);
       // byte[] pic = stream.ToArray();
        try
        {
            conDB.Open();
            OleDbCommand command = new OleDbCommand();
            command.Connection = conDB;
            command.CommandText = "insert into abaanaCC (CCSpn_CODE,CCFname,CCLname,CCMname,CCDOB,CCgender,CCSchool,CaClass,CCVillage,CCSiblings,CCGuardian,CCContact,CCImage)" +
                " values ('" + spn_codetxt.Text + "','" + txtfname.Text + "','" + lnametxt.Text + "','" + mnametxt.Text + "','" + DOBDTPicker1.Text + "','" + gendercomboBox.Text + "','" + schtxt.Text + "','" + classcomboBox.Text + "','" + villatxt.Text + "','" + siblingscombobx.Text + "','" + guardiantxt.Text + "','" + contacttxt.Text + "',@IMG) ";
            command.Parameters.Add(new OleDbParameter("@IMG",imageBt));
            //command.Parameters.AddWithValue("@IMG",pic);
            command.ExecuteNonQuery();
            MessageBox.Show("Record Saved");
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            MessageBox.Show("Unable to save" + ex);
        }
        conDB.Close();
    }
```

then this is for datagridview

```
private void Update_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        // TODO: This line of code loads data into the 'abaanaDataSet.abaanaCC' table. You can move, or remove it, as needed.
        this.abaanaCCTableAdapter.Fill(this.abaanaDataSet.abaanaCC);

    }
```

am using the cell click event, such that when a cell is clicked, the contents of that row, that is the `CCImage` and `CCSpn_CODE` appear. The `CCSpn_CODE` appears in `Ptxtspn_code` `textBox` just fine. The problem is the byte[] image that i'm converting. it's displaying only the image of the first row. how can i make `PpicBox` display whatever image from whatever row i click on the `datagridView`just like `Ptxtspn_code` `textBox`

```
 private void abaanaCCDataGridView_CellClick(object sender, DataGridViewCellEventArgs e)
    {
            this.Ptxtspn_code.Text = this.abaanaCCDataGridView.SelectedRows[0].Cells[this.dataGridViewTextBoxColumn2.Name].Value.ToString();
this.abaanaCCTableAdapter.Fill(this.abaanaDataSet.abaanaCC);           
byte[] mydata = (byte[])this.abaanaDataSet.abaanaCC.Rows[0]["CCImage"];
          MemoryStream stream = new MemoryStream(mydata);           
         this.PpicBox.Image =Image.FromStream(stream);

 }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Note:**

- In `CellClick` event you should check if click is not on row header or column header
- `e.RowIndex` is row index of clicked cell, and `e.ColumnIndex` is index of column of clicked cell
- To get values of clicked row you can use:

  - `yourDGV.Rows[e.RowIndex].Cells["GridColumnName"].value`
  - `yourDGV.Rows[e.RowIndex].Cells[2].Value`
  - `((DataRowView)yourDGV.Rows[e.RowIndex].DataBoundItem)[2]`
  - `((DataRowView)yourDGV.Rows[e.RowIndex].DataBoundItem)["DataTableColumnName"]`
- I didn't have any idea about why you fill abaanaCC in `CellClick` because you load data in form load event and so all values including CCImage is present id your data table. So I removed it. It seems that you should fill it only when you want to load data not here in cell click.

For example your code may like this:

```
private void abaanaCCDataGridView_CellClick(object sender, DataGridViewCellEventArgs e)
{
    if (e.RowIndex < 0 || e.ColumnIndex < 0)
        return;

    this.Ptxtspn_code.Text = this.abaanaCCDataGridView.Rows[e.RowIndex].Cells[this.dataGridViewTextBoxColumn2.Name].Value.ToString();       
    byte[] mydata = (byte[])this.abaanaDataSet.abaanaCC.Rows[r.RowIndex]["CCImage"];
    MemoryStream stream = new MemoryStream(mydata);           
    this.PpicBox.Image =Image.FromStream(stream);
}
```

Comment: please help me out [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/37520758/how-to-add-the-value-of-a-column-in-database)