# How to Hold a selection from datagridview

Tags: c#, winforms, datagridview

Am using the `cell_click` event in my `datagridview` such that whatever i select is displayed in `this.spncodelabel.Text` `label` and `this.form3picbox.Image` `pictureBox` and so on of which all work fine BUT my problem is every time i select a record the selection mode goes back to the first row. How can i hold the selection to that particular row or to whatever record i have selected in order to show that i have selected from that particular row

here's my code for `datagridview` `cell_click` event

```
   private void dataGridView1_CellClick(object sender, DataGridViewCellEventArgs e)
        {

            OleDbCommand command = new OleDbCommand();
            command.Connection = conDB;
            string query = "select CCSpn_CODE,CCLname,CCFname,CCMname,CCDOB,CCgender,CCSchool,CaClass,CCVillage,CCSiblings,CCGuardian,CCContact,CCImage from abaanaCC";
           CCSpn_CODE,CCFname,CCLname,CCMname,CCDOB,CCgender,CCSchool,CaClass,CCVillage,CCSiblings,CCGuardian,CCContact,CCImage from abaanaCC where CCSpn_CODE = '" + txtspn_codesch.Text + "'";

                command.CommandText = query;
                OleDbDataAdapter da = new OleDbDataAdapter(command);
                DataTable dt = new DataTable();
                da.Fill(dt);

                dataGridView1.DataSource = dt;
                if (e.RowIndex < 0 || e.ColumnIndex < 0)
                    return;
                this.spncodelabel.Text = this.dataGridView1.Rows[e.RowIndex].Cells["CCSpn_CODE"].Value.ToString();
                byte[] mydata = (byte[])dt.Rows[e.RowIndex]["CCImage"];
                MemoryStream stream = new MemoryStream(mydata);
                this.form3picbox.Image = Image.FromStream(stream);
                this.lblfname.Text = this.dataGridView1.Rows[e.RowIndex].Cells["CCFname"].Value.ToString();
                this.lbllastname.Text = this.dataGridView1.Rows[e.RowIndex].Cells["CCLname"].Value.ToString();
                this.lblguardian.Text = this.dataGridView1.Rows[e.RowIndex].Cells["CCGuardian"].Value.ToString();
                this.lblcontact.Text = this.dataGridView1.Rows[e.RowIndex].Cells["CCContact"].Value.ToString();
                this.lblschool.Text = this.dataGridView1.Rows[e.RowIndex].Cells["CCSchool"].Value.ToString();
                this.lblvillage.Text = this.dataGridView1.Rows[e.RowIndex].Cells["CCVillage"].Value.ToString();
                this.lblgender.Text = this.dataGridView1.Rows[e.RowIndex].Cells["CCgender"].Value.ToString();
                this.doblbl.Text = this.dataGridView1.Rows[e.RowIndex].Cells["CCDOB"].Value.ToString();                        

       }
```

Comment: It is obviously because of `dataGridView1.DataSource = dt;`. You don't need to fill your data table in every cell click event. Just fill your data table at form load or wherever else you load your data.

Comment: apparently am getting the "index out of range" error

Comment: In which line you have index out of range?

Comment: sorry my bad....thanks you very much!!!

Comment: you can take a look at my other [answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/32854111/3110834) about your issue. Hope you find it helpful:)

Comment: thanks..i had mistakenly commented `da.fill(dt);` but now working point