# How To Add Value To A Column And Update Database

Tags: c#, .net, sql-server, winforms, datagridview

I am trying to add the value of the column **Annual_Fees** in `dataGridViewAFp1` to a new value **AF2** from the textbox `txtp1AF.Text` that I did convert to integer. Then the result from the addition **ResultAF** is converted back to string **updatedAF** and that's the value to be updated in the database. I did initialize variable **AF11** to 0. The query does update the selected columns. The idea is to get whatever value is in **AF2** and add it to whatever value is in that column and row specifically which i put in **AF11** in the **database** hence the updated value **updatedAF**. Here's what I have done so far but doesn't seem to be working. The values are not adding up.

```
 private void btnEnterAFp1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {            
        if (string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(txtp1AF.Text))
        {                

            MessageBox.Show("Please Enter fee","Oops",MessageBoxButtons.OK,MessageBoxIcon.Warning);
        }
        else
        {
            if (dataGridViewAFp1.Rows[0].Cells["Annual_Fees"].Value != null)
            {
                conn.Open();
                SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand();
                cmd.Connection = conn;

                int.TryParse(dataGridViewAFp1.Rows[0].Cells["Annual_Fees"].Value.ToString(), out AF11);
                AF2 = Convert.ToInt32(txtp1AF.Text);
                ResultAF = AF11 + AF2;
                String updatedAF = Convert.ToString(ResultAF);

                cmd.CommandText = @"Update P1 set Annual_Fees=@af where Sponsorship_Status = 'Sponsored' OR Sponsorship_Status = 'Unsponsored' OR Sponsorship_Status = 'Formerly Sponsored' ";
                cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@af", updatedAF);
                cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
                DataTable dt = new DataTable();
                SqlDataAdapter adap = new SqlDataAdapter(cmd);
                adap.Fill(dt);
                //dataGridViewAFp1.DataSource = dt;
                conn.Close();
                MessageBox.Show("Record Updated Successfully ");
                txtp1AF.Text = " "; 
            }
```

Comment: Are you getting a error message ?

Comment: I was getting `Input string not valid` that was before  i updated my code to that. No error message, the values are not adding up

Comment: Try to add brackets in your query :[Annual_Fees] and [Sponsorship_Status]

Comment: query works fine, the logic is not - the idea is, whatever value is in variable AF2 is added to whatever value is in that Annual Fees Column

Comment: Your variables  ResultAF, AF11 ,AF2 are declared as int ?

Comment: yes they are declared as int

Comment: Check `cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();` must return value greater than 0. If returned value is 0 - that mean no rows was updated

Comment: @Fabio i don't seem to be getting the **ResultAF** value, I am instead getting **AF2** value as the updated value and yet i want it to be **ResultAF**

Comment: @sea50 are you sure that dataGridViewAFp1.Rows[0].Cells["Annual_Fees"].Value.ToString() containt a numeric value ?

Comment: yes that column contains a numeric value

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming everything else is working fine on your side, the main problem is that you're using the same `Update` command contained in your `cmd` variable, that you used before to update the database, to try to fill your `dt` with the updated values. Instead you must use a `Select` command for that purpose, as follows:

Change this:

```
DataTable dt = new DataTable();
SqlDataAdapter adap = new SqlDataAdapter(cmd);
adap.Fill(dt);
//dataGridViewAFp1.DataSource = dt;
```

to this:

```
 DataTable dt = new DataTable();
 SqlDataAdapter adap = new SqlDataAdapter("select * from P1", conn);
 adap.Fill(dt);
 dataGridViewAFp1.DataSource = dt;
```

**EDIT:** Adding full working code. In this sample, column `ListPrice` (column index 9) is updated for the first 2 data rows from `100.00` to `200.00`(watch). I'm using your code, just changing table and column names.

```
    private void btnEnterAFp1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        SqlConnection conn = new SqlConnection(@"Data Source=(LocalDB)\MSSQLLocalDB;AttachDbFilename=|DataDirectory|\AdventureWorks2014.mdf;Integrated Security=True;Connect Timeout=30");
        decimal AF2;
        decimal AF11;
        decimal ResultAF;

        if (string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(txtp1AF.Text))
        {

            MessageBox.Show("Please Enter fee", "Oops", MessageBoxButtons.OK, MessageBoxIcon.Warning);
        }
        else
        {
            if (dataGridViewAFp1.Rows[0].Cells[9].Value != null)
            {
                conn.Open();
                SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand();
                cmd.Connection = conn;

                decimal.TryParse(dataGridViewAFp1.Rows[0].Cells[9].Value.ToString(), out AF11);
                AF2 = Convert.ToDecimal(txtp1AF.Text);
                ResultAF = AF11 + AF2;
                String updatedAF = Convert.ToString(ResultAF);

                cmd.CommandText = @"Update Production.Product set ListPrice=@af where Name = 'Adjustable Race' OR Name = 'Bearing Ball'";
                cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@af", updatedAF);
                int n = cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();

                DataTable dt = new DataTable();
                SqlDataAdapter adap = new SqlDataAdapter("select * from Production.Product", conn);
                adap.Fill(dt);

                dataGridViewAFp1.DataSource = dt;

                conn.Close();
                MessageBox.Show("Record Updated Successfully ");
                txtp1AF.Text = " ";
            }
        }
    }
```

[image]

Comment: still values are not adding up, for instance in the **Annual_Fees** column I have 100 then I enter a new value 100, the current value in **Annual_Fees** column should be 200. But they are not adding up

Comment: Did you step through using the debugger to check your intermediate calculations?

Comment: ` int.TryParse(dataGridViewAFp1.Rows[0].Cells["Annual_Fees"].Value.ToString(), out AF11);` turns out that the value of **Annual_Fees** column is not passed to variable **AF11**

Comment: but how can i get the value from the rows in that column from the dataTable may be it will work that way

Comment: If the `dataGridViewAFp1.Rows[0].Cells["Annual_Fees"].Value` has a dot in it, for instance `100.00`, then you can't use `int.TryParse()`, you have to use, for instance, `decimal.TryParse()`.

Comment: check if `TryParse()` is returning `true` or `false`.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/113348/discussion-between-sea50-and-jstreet).